# how to specify sorting of objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have 20 apartments on the index page. I want to specify which apartments are shown at the top of the page and which at the bottom, ect. I guess it's a kind of sorting.

What's the best approach for this kind of rendering of objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is to add a new attribute to apartments, called `sort_order`, for example.

Then, by manipulating its values you can achieve desired sorting. For example, if you want an apartment to be showed first (user pays you money to promote it, or whatever), you can set its `sort_order` to `MAX(sort_order) + 1`.

Then at display time you do this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM apartments
ORDER BY sort_order DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

Actual implementation will probably be a little bit more complex, but you get the idea.